# DAC via I2C: detect error conditions

Tags: avr, atmel, dac

We are using a MAX517 DAC-device as slave and an ATmega8535 controller as master. Communication errors can be readily detected by comparing (TWSR & 0xF8) with 0x08 for Start, 0x18 for address transmission, and 0x28 for data transmission, respectively.

But I'm wondering where those values come from. In the Atmel datasheet I find the usual symbols START (for 0x08), MT_SLA_ACK (for 0x18), and MT_DATA_ACK (for 0x28), but not the numerical values. Neither are the values mentioned in the MAX517 datasheet.

Comment: Found it myself. Those are the values used to define the corresponding symbols in utils/twi.h of the avr-8-gnu-toolchain.

Comment: please remember it's perfectly okay to post an answer to your own question, especially if it might help others who encounter the same problem.